# Need to level OSB board for LVP, pros and cons of using roofing shingles?

Tags: flooring, subfloor, vinyl-flooring, underlayment

I am looking into inexpensive options to level OSB for installing luxury vinyl planks.

I read an article that talks about using roofing shingles to level out subfloors before installing hardwood.

I am wondering if this could work for leveling the OSB under the carpeting I ripped up in a mobile home.

I looked into self levelling compounds, but I could only find one that works on OSB and it's expensive for the amount of leveling that it's possibly going to need.

If shingles could work, would they have to be screwed down as they could shift under floating vinyl planks?
Does anyone have any experience with this method?
What pros or cons could there be for using roof shingles?

ADDITIONAL INFO:

There is no moisture problem. I would say the problem areas are unlevel due to installation.

Adding pics.[image: tilt1] [image: tilt2]First two pics are a section 4 feet by 4 inches Looks like the board was put there to fill a gap for reasons unknown. It's not level and it's tilted toward the wall.
[image: mwall1]
Marriage wall gap that runs through one half the trailer. it's about 2 inches deep.
[image: mwall4]The marriage wall in the other half. It's wavy and uneven. Don't know what to do about that either. I fear it may affect the LVP over time.
[image: kitch]This section runs about 4" x 4". Thanks!

Comment: In what way is the OSB unlevel (slanted, bowed, stepped, lumpy?)  be aware that self-leveling compount flows like water to level itself (when applied, then it sets) so if your foundations are on a lean it will slosh to one side of the room. (this could be common in mobile homes)

Comment: At the suggestion of Freeman, I'm copying this comment to the question.  .......
To the OP, OH GEEZE, you have an issue there. WOW. I think the only way LVT would work would be for you to putdown an additional sub-floor (like 1/2 particle board), leveled with the shingles/shims underneath as you originally asked about. That would be a HUGE, time consuming job. Even that's a sketchy solution. I'd give up on the idea of LVT and go with a much harder flooring product. Use a combination of shims and leveling compound, and make the best of it.There are products that are much stiffer than LVT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would totally impossible to get good results using that method. LVT is pretty flexible. I've remodeled a rental house and personally (not a contractor) installed LVT.  It turned out pretty good, but I did need a leveling compound for part of the floor.   Our church also replaced a bunch of carpet in the hallways with LVT and the installer missed a bit of debris here and there and even tiny bits telegraph thru and you can see it.

The method you are asking about mentioned hardwoods which is a totally different ball game. With LVT, I'm sure you'd end up with a wavy, ugly mess on your hands using shingles.

Why is the OSB not "level"? Water damage? poor installation? You may not needs as much leveling compound as you think just to at least hit the worst parts.   Hard to know without pics and more info.

Comment: Addressing the _reason_ for the not level subfloor seems to be as important as getting it level

Comment: @FreeMan yep.  agreed +   I think I said that in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Yes you did. I was emphasizing that point. ;)

Comment: To the OP, OH GEEZE, you have an issue there. WOW.  I think the only way LVT would work would be for you to putdown an additional sub-floor (like 1/2 particle board), leveled with the shingles/shims underneath as you originally asked about.  That would be a HUGE, time consuming job. Even that's a sketchy solution. I'd give up on the idea of LVT and go with a much harder flooring product. Use a combination of shims and leveling compound, and make the best of it.  Product recommendations are off topic here, but there are good options in flooring that's very stiff and tough.

Comment: You may want to put that comment on the question to ensure the OP gets notified about it. It's a very valid point, and now that she's given a check mark, she may not come back to look at updates.

Comment: Since my question was specifically about using roofing shingles to level the subfloor  I accepted George's answer. He has good points and I have decided not to use shingles. I am going to submit another question that addresses the subfloor issues.